# Decimal Rounding Issue When Using Cast

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working to try and get a SQL query to show me only two decimal places.  Unfortunately it is a very complex query and every combination of "decimal(18,2)" that I have tried does not work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                 Company_Name AS Company, CASE WHEN isnull((CAST(IsNull(SUM(Margin), 0) / CASE isnull(SUM(invoiceamt), 0) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE SUM(invoiceamt) 
                 END * 100 AS decimal(18, 2)) / 70), 0) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE (CAST(IsNull(SUM(Margin), 0) / CASE isnull(SUM(invoiceamt), 0) 
                 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE SUM(invoiceamt) END * 100 AS decimal(18, 2)) / 70) END * 100 AS Service_Goal
FROM            v_cbi_Agr_Mo_Billing_History3
WHERE        (1 = 1) AND (dbo.udf_cbi_InternalCompanyName() <> Company_Name) AND (DATEDIFF(mm, GETDATE(), MonthStart) BETWEEN 0 AND 0) AND 
                 (AGR_Type_Desc IN ('Agreement1', 'Agreement2', 'Agreement3'))
GROUP BY Company_Name
HAVING        (SUM(Margin) <> 0) OR
                 (SUM(InvoiceAmt) <> 0)
ORDER BY Company
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to help with this! What error are you getting? You can try splitting out all of the components in the `Service_Goal` column and once they all work as expected you can try to put them back or just write them to a temp table. Also, sometimes it helps when you add a decimal to your isnulls and integers to keep it from casting INT: (`ISNULL(x, 0.)` `x/70.`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are casting this block as a decimal and then dividing by 70 which is resulting in more decimal places.

```
Cast(Isnull(Sum(@margin), 0) / CASE Isnull(Sum(@invoiceamt), 0) 
                                    WHEN 0 THEN 1 
                                    ELSE Sum(@invoiceamt) 
                                  END * 100 AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
```

You could change it to this which does all the calulcations and then casts as a decimal (10,2). I'm not sure how you wanted it all calculated.

```
Cast(Isnull(Sum(@margin), 0) / CASE Isnull(Sum(@invoiceamt), 0) 
                                    WHEN 0 THEN 1 
                                    ELSE Sum(@invoiceamt) 
                                  END * 100 / 70 AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the result of the expression to the desired precision. (The inner cast is used to avoid integer division).

For example:

```
select 
    cast( 100 / cast(77 as decimal(10,2) ) as decimal(10,2) ), 
    100/cast(77 as decimal(10,2))
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1.30                                    1.29870129870
```